# unable to get subtotal, total and sales tax to show in gui

Tags: java, swing

To start, for some reason the mathematics are screwed in my gui so a 20.61 book keeps showing its total as 16.43 or something similar. aside from that i'm attempting to create fields for the sales tax, total and subtotal to be shown in the application...but the only one that shows up is the Total.
how do I create the sales tax and subtotal sop they show the same as total?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class JavaProgram extends JFrame
{
    private final String BOOK_DATA_FILENAME = "bookData1.txt";
    private final int LIST_ROWS_VISIBLE = 5;
    private final String PROGRAM_NAME = "Books'r'Us";

    private JPanel bookPanel;
    private JPanel controlPanel;
    private JPanel cartPanel;
    private JPanel checkOutPanel;

    private JList bookList;
    private JList cartList;

    private JButton addToCartButton;
    private JButton removeFromCartButton;
    private JButton clearCartButton;

    private JTextField totalText;
    private double total = 0.00;

    private Vector<Book> books = new Vector<Book>();
    private Vector<Book> cart = new Vector<Book>();

    public JavaProgram() throws IOException
    {
        setTitle( PROGRAM_NAME );
        setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        buildBookPanel();
        buildControlPanel();
        buildCartPanel();
        buildCheckOutPanel();

        add( bookPanel, BorderLayout.WEST );
        add( controlPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER );
        add( cartPanel, BorderLayout.EAST );
        add( checkOutPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

        pack();

        setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        setVisible( true );
    }

    private void buildBookPanel() throws IOException
    {
        bookPanel = new JPanel();
        bookPanel.setBorder( BorderFactory.createTitledBorder( "Books" ) );

        loadBooks();

        bookList = new JList( books );
        bookList.setVisibleRowCount( LIST_ROWS_VISIBLE );
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( bookList );

        bookPanel.add( scrollPane );
    }

    private void loadBooks() throws IOException
    {
        File bookFile = new File( BOOK_DATA_FILENAME );
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner( bookFile );

        while( inputFile.hasNext() )
        {
            String bookDataLine = inputFile.nextLine();
            String[] token = bookDataLine.split( "," );

            Book newBook = new Book();

            newBook.setTitle( token[0] );
            newBook.setAuthor( token[1] );
            newBook.setPrice( Double.parseDouble( token[2] ) );

            books.add( newBook );
        }

        inputFile.close();
    }

    private void buildControlPanel()
    {
        controlPanel = new JPanel();
        controlPanel.setBorder( BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder( 30, 10, 10, 10 ) );

        controlPanel.setLayout( new GridLayout( 4, 1 ) );

        addToCartButton = new JButton( "Add to Cart" );
        addToCartButton.addActionListener( new AddButtonListener() );

        removeFromCartButton = new JButton( "Remove from Cart" );
        removeFromCartButton.addActionListener( new RemoveButtonListener() );

        clearCartButton = new JButton( "Clear Cart" );
        clearCartButton.addActionListener( new ClearButtonListener() );

        controlPanel.add( addToCartButton );
        controlPanel.add( removeFromCartButton ); 
        controlPanel.add( clearCartButton );
    }

    private void buildCartPanel()
    {
        cartPanel = new JPanel();
        cartPanel.setBorder( BorderFactory.createTitledBorder( "Shopping Cart" ) );

        cartList = new JList();
        cartList.setVisibleRowCount( LIST_ROWS_VISIBLE );
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( cartList );

        cartPanel.add( scrollPane );
    }

    private void buildCheckOutPanel()
    {
        checkOutPanel = new JPanel();

      checkOutPanel.add( new JLabel( "Subtotal" ) );

      totalText = new JTextField( 10 );
        totalText.setEditable( false );

      checkOutPanel.add( new JLabel( "Sales Tax" ) );

      totalText = new JTextField( 10 );
        totalText.setEditable( false );

      checkOutPanel.add( new JLabel( "Total: " ) );

        totalText = new JTextField( 10 );
        totalText.setEditable( false );

        checkOutPanel.add( totalText );
    }

    private void addToCart( Book book )
    {
        cart.add( book );
        cartList.setListData( cart );
        total += book.getPrice();
        updateTotal();
    }

    private void removeFromCart( Book book, int index )
    {
        cart.remove( index );
        cartList.setListData( cart );
        total -= book.getPrice();
        updateTotal();
    }

    private void updateTotal()
    {
        DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat( "$##,##0.00" );
        totalText.setText( fmt.format( total ) );
    }

    private class AddButtonListener implements ActionListener
   {  
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
      {
            if( bookList.getSelectedValue()!=null )
         {
            Book selected = (Book) bookList.getSelectedValue();
            addToCart( selected );
                bookList.clearSelection();
         }
            else
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( JavaProgram.this,
                        "Please select a book before adding to cart.", 
                        PROGRAM_NAME, 
                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE );
      }
   }

    private class RemoveButtonListener implements ActionListener
   {      
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
      {
            int selectedIndex = cartList.getSelectedIndex();

            if( selectedIndex != -1 )
         {
            Book selected = (Book) cartList.getSelectedValue();
            removeFromCart( selected, selectedIndex );
         }
            else
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( JavaProgram.this,
                        "Please select a book from the cart.", 
                        PROGRAM_NAME, 
                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE );
      }
   }

    private class ClearButtonListener implements ActionListener
   {      
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
      {
            final int YES = 0;
            final int NO = 1;

            int choice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog( JavaProgram.this,
                            "Clear shopping cart?",
                            PROGRAM_NAME,
                            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION );

            if( choice==YES )
            {
                cart.clear();
                cartList.setListData( cart );
                total = 0.00;
                updateTotal();
            }
        }
   }

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {
        new JavaProgram();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's `Book`? And the "book file"?

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (**minimal** code that **compiles for us** and demonstrates the problem).

Answer (score 0):

add 2 more JTextFields for sub-total and sales-tax:

```
private JTextField subTotal;
private JTextField salesTax;
private JTextField totalText;
```

modify your buildCheckOutPanel() method:

```
private void buildCheckOutPanel()
{
    checkOutPanel = new JPanel();

  checkOutPanel.add( new JLabel( "Subtotal" ) );

  subTotal = new JTextField( 10 );
    subTotal.setEditable( false );
    checkOutPanel.add( subTotal );

  checkOutPanel.add( new JLabel( "Sales Tax" ) );

  salesTax = new JTextField( 10 );
    salesTax.setEditable( false );
    checkOutPanel.add( salesTax );

  checkOutPanel.add( new JLabel( "Total: " ) );

    totalText = new JTextField( 10 );
    totalText.setEditable( false );

    checkOutPanel.add( totalText );
}
```

modify updateTotal() method:

```
private void updateTotal()
{
    DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat( "$##,##0.00" );
    subTotal.setText( fmt.format( total ) );
    double tax =total*0.1; //if sales-tax is 10% of total
    salesTax.setText( fmt.format(tax) );
    totalText.setText(fmt.format(total+tax));

}
```

Comment: I did everything you showed, and still nothing... I honestly have no idea how to create a n mcve with this problem...and quit frankly its irritating me that i'm unable to figure this thing out...

Comment: @kingvicious ... i've tried this code .. it worked perfect for me ... i'd say, instead of taking input from a file ... try to implement this code for some static input ... later change it to input from a file